# Scroll snapping overridden by child element

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm developing a website with scroll snapping. I'm kinda new to web dev. Here is the code to my App.vue where I initialize the snapping:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="main-scroll-snap" @scroll="handleScroll">
      <Menu/>
      <FullPage>
        <FirstPage :scroll-pos="scrollY"/>
      </FullPage>
      <FullPage>Test2</FullPage>
      <FullPage>Test3</FullPage>
      <FullPage>Test4</FullPage>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<style scoped>

.main-scroll-snap {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

</style>
```

So the FullPage.vue is basically just this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="full-page">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>

.full-page {
  scroll-snap-align: center;

  overflow-y: hidden;

  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

</style>
```

My issue is that whenever my mouse is on an element INSIDE FullPage (for instance, FirstPage.vue, as seen in the App.vue), the scrolling effect of the scroll snap is overridden by this element, and the scrolling of the page doesnt happen anymore. So if I have my mouse on an image, and try to scroll, it wont work, because it tries to scroll the image. But if I have it on the background, it correctly scrolls and snaps, as stated in the `main-scroll-snap` tag.

the `box-sizing: border-box;` is an attempt of chatgpt to solve the problem, which of course, didnt work. How could I make it so that these elements don't override the scroll of the main div inside my App.vue?

I tried adding a `z-index: 100;` to the `main-scroll-snap` CSS, but it didn't change anything. I've also tried using `overflow-y: hidden;` on the FullPage, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `pointer-events: none;` CSS attribute deactivates interaction with elements that are contained inside, so if I add this to the `full-page` class CSS, elements wont interrupt the scroll.